# Laravel nao gera erro ao processar formulario com 'post'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

Estou fazendo um curso de Laravel, e no curso o instrutor usou um formulario que aponta pra lugar nenhum pra mostrar um erro do tipo `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Ate ai, tudo bem, mas ao processar o formulario o Laravel nao gera erro nenhum, enquanto o do instrutor, com o mesmo codigo, gera. Por que?

Template da pagina:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title>Controle de Series</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>@yield('cabecalho')<!-- local onde sera inserido o cabecalho da pagina --></h1>
      </div>

      @yield('conteudo') <!-- local onde sera inserido o conteudo da pagina -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pagina do formulario:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('cabecalho')
Adicionar Serie
@endsection

@section('conteudo')
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id='nome' class='form-control'/>
    </div>

    <button class='btn btn-primary'>Adicionar</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

Estou usando Laravel 5.8, com PHP 7.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` seja um erro de rota no Laravel, talvez ele esteja usando POST e você usando o GET.
Abre teu arquivo de rotas e verifica.

Mas um exemplo básico seria assim.

```
Route::post("/first_page",function(){
     return view('welcome');
})
```

Caso você adicione na sua URL `/first_page` ele vai dar um erro de `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` por conta que você deveria acessar a rota como POST e não por GET.

Comment: Erro dele ainda vai continuar dando notfound faltou por @csrf depois da abertura do form

Comment: Sim concordo, mas creio que a pergunta foi editada então pode ser que tenha existido @csrf.